# distanceInMeters Problems with arrays and sort

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to sort my TableView by distance, but I have mixed up:( Please help me if You can, I would appreciate it, really :(

I have an array with 100 objects.

```
var malls: [Mall] = [

    Mall(name: "Европейский",  type: "торговый центр", image: "europe.jpg", time: "с 10.00 до 22.00",
         timeWeek: "с 10.00 до 23.00", city: "Москва", location: "Киевская",
         adress: "г. Москва, Киевского вокзала площадь, д.2", cinemaName:"formulakino.png",
         productName: "perekrestok.png", numShop: "309", website: "http://europe-tc.ru", schemeWeb:"http://www.europe-tc.ru/shops/", longitude:37.566, latitude:55.745),

    Mall(name: "Золотой Вавилон Ростокино",  type: "торговый центр", image: "vavilon.jpg", time: "с 10.00 до 22.00",
         timeWeek: "с 10.00 до 22.00", city: "Москва", location: "Проспект Мира",
         adress: "г. Москва, Проспект Мира, д. 211", cinemaName: "Люксор",
         productName: "okay.png", numShop: "280", website: "http://zolotoy-vavilon.ru/rostokino", schemeWeb:"http://www.zolotoy-vavilon.ru/rostokino/map", longitude:37.663, latitude:55.846), ]
```

and so on.. sorry for Cyrillic

and after override func tableView I have this

```
func locationManager(_  manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{


    let currentLocation = locations[0]


    if (currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 ) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let coords = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        **let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)**
        let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords)
        print (distanceInMeters)
    }

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
    let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: mall.image)
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.nameLabel.text = mall.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = mall.location
    cell.typeLabel.text = mall.time


    return cell

}
```

I have problem in this row

```
let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
```

**Use of unresolved identifier 'mall'**

How can I fix it? and how to do sort by directions? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use of unresolved identifier 'mall'

=> There is nothing named **"mall"** in the scope of the function `locationManager didUpdateLocations`. Meaning: `locationManager didUpdateLocations` has no clue what happens inside of `tableView cellForRowAt indexPath` and vice versa.

---

You could solve this problem by applying following steps to your code:

1. Move the distance calculation from
   `locationManager didUpdateLocations`
   to
   `tableView cellForRowAt indexPath`
2. add a property to your class that stores the current position:
   `var currentPosition: CLLocation? = nil`
3. Store the position you receive in `locationManager didUpdateLocations` to the `currentPosition` property
4. Add `self.tableView.reloadData()` after you received and assigned the position
5. Use the `mall` and the `currentPosition` in `cellForRowAt` to calculate the distance and update the `distanceLabel`
6. Keep in mind that `currentPosition` can be `nil` and the distance can not be calculated => make label empty or add something like "unknown distance" to it

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the index of your array:

```
let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: malls[0].latitude, longitude: malls[0].longitude)
```

Comment: wow! thank you and how to do 
        cell.distanceLabel = distanceInMeters

Comment: About  `cell.distanceLabel = distanceInMeters` I don't what you're talking about

Comment: please how to 
    
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell.distanceLabel = distanceInMeters
} 
distanceInMeters is unresolved identifier(

Comment: @FedericoMalagoni Don't ask people to vote on your answer.  If they find it useful, they will vote and the OP will accept.  The OP also cannot upvote your question because they only have 1 rep.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to sort your array of malls based on their distance to the user's current location.

I would suggest you add a var `distanceToUser` to the Mall object. (Make it an optional Double)

In `locationManager.didUpdateLocations()`, loop through the array of malls and use the `CLLocation` `distance(from:)` function to calculate the distance from the new user location to each mall, and store that value in each mall's `distanceToUser` property.

Once you have populated the `distanceToUser` properties of your array of malls, you can sort the array by that property. Finally, call your table view's `reloadData()` method. Write your `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` method to display your cells in the existing array order.

The reason to include a distance property in your mall objects is performance. The location manager function to calculate the distance between 2 points is actually somewhat time-consuming (It has to do 3D trig in order to get an accurate calculate on the surface of the globe.) You want to avoid calculating the distance value over and over. Instead, by batch-calculating the distance to a newly updated location, sorting can treat the distance values as known constants that are calculated once per Mall object when the location changes.

If you have a lot of mall objects you might need to do the distance calculations in a background thread and then call the main thread to reload your table view once the calculations are complete, but you can write your calculation code to run on the main thread and then go back and refactor it if you find your UI lags when there is a location update.

You'll also want to configure the location manager to only update the current location when it changes by fairly large amounts. Either that or put in code that compares the new location to the old one and only re-sorts the malls array if the distance has changed enough to affect the sort order of your Malls array. (At the highest sensitivity reading, the location manager gives you an almost constant stream of tiny location changes, which would mean you were recalculating your distances and re-sorting your Malls array constantly.)